# ASP.net Project using SQL database, checking values and "rebinding"

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I Have a ASP.net project that had a few listboxs which are currently populated by the server with an SQL database

for example for 1 listbox

```
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
string queryShrewsbury = "SELECT Callsign, Info FROM " + currentTableName + " WHERE Location Like 'Shrewsbury'";using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryShrewsbury))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    Shrewsbury_Listbox.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    Shrewsbury_Listbox.DataValueField = "Info";
                    Shrewsbury_Listbox.DataTextField = "Callsign";
                    Shrewsbury_Listbox.DataBind();
                    con.Close();

                }
```

At present i have the following on my HTML Script markup

```
<script>
            setInterval(function () {
                $('#refresh').click();

            }, 30000);


        </script>
```

which is linked to a button that will "click" a refresh button, to the BIND() method above

So it rebinds the the listboxs every 30 seconds. but this seems like a bit of a "hack workaround"

is there anyway i can have the application "check" when a change has been made to the SQL, or at least check every x seconds and rebind if different?

I have tried using an update panel, but the BIND() method is in the codebehind, so I don't think it would help.

I thought about calling an AJAX method but the BIND() method cannot be static.

Sorry if this isn't explained very well. Any help I would appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JoeIrby for his help, I went a slightly different way and used the built in "sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats" and ran an SQL query for "last_user_update"

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateQuery))
            {
                SqlCommand whenUpdated = new SqlCommand(updateQuery, con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = whenUpdated.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    string SqlUpdateTime = rdr["last_user_update"].ToString();
                    if (SqlUpdateTime != "")
                    {
                        DateTime SQLasTime = Convert.ToDateTime(SqlUpdateTime);
                        double inMilliseconds = SQLasTime.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalMilliseconds;
                        if (inMilliseconds > time)
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                con.Close();
                return false;
```

then did a simple AJAX call and passed in the current time in milliseconds

```
setInterval(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "Shropshire.aspx/needToUpdate",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    datatype: 'Json',
                    data: "{time:" + n + "}",
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        if (data.d === true) {
                            document.getElementById("<%=refreshPanel.ClientID%>").click();
                            var d1 = new Date();
                            var n1 = d1.getTime();
                            n = n1;
                        }

                    },
                    Error: function (Error) {
                        console.log("error");
                    }
                });
            }, interval);
```

Then if it returned true (if the sql was updated elsewhere), I updated the panel which wrapped the listboxes and rebound the listboxes.

The AJAX call I had running every 10 seconds.

I hope this helps other people.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, a cleaner (and still relatively simple) approach would be to do an AJAX call to the server every X seconds, and have that AJAX call return a simple true/false to the javascript indicating whether it needs to reload the page.  If necessary, the javascript could pass in some parameter(s) to the AJAX call such as the timestamp of the last known record, if the server needs additional information to be able to determine whether to return true or false.

Probably the "best" approach is to use WebSockets to maintain a two-way connection to the server, where the server can actually push the data back to the javascript in real time, but that adds a level of complexity you might not want to go to.

(Keep in mind that ASP.Net WebForms is a relatively old architecture at this point, and it was designed in the days before AJAX was commonly used.  So, any solution we come up with will be a little bit of an awkward fit into a WebForms project.)

As an example, here's one way you could implement the approach I'm suggesting.  I haven't actually tested this, so hopefully I have no major mistakes!

First, add a hidden input with runat=server somewhere in your HTML markup. We're going to use this to pass a number from our codebehind, to our javascript:

```
<input id='hiddenRowCount' type='hidden' runat='server' />
```

Second, in your codebehind, let's refactor your existing code slightly so that the data is fetched by a separate function.  This is because we're also going to call the getData() function from our AJAX handler.

```
private DataTable getData()
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
    string queryShrewsbury = "SELECT Callsign, Info FROM " + currentTableName + " WHERE Location Like 'Shrewsbury'";

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryShrewsbury))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;

        using (var da = new DataAdapter(cmd))
        {
          da.Fill(ds, "Results");
        }
    }

    return ds.Tables["Results"];
}

private void bindData()
{
    var dataTable = getData();

    Shrewsbury_Listbox.DataSource = dataTable;
    Shrewsbury_Listbox.DataValueField = "Info";
    Shrewsbury_Listbox.DataTextField = "Callsign";
    Shrewsbury_Listbox.DataBind();

    // pass row count to the hidden input control
    hiddenRowCount.Value = dataTable.Rows.Count.ToString();
}
```

Third, create the server-side function which will handle the AJAX call.  The javascript will provide the value of hiddenRowCount as a parameter to the server.  We're using PageMethods here, which you can read more about at http://aspalliance.com/1922_PageMethods_In_ASPNET_AJAX.2

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool NeedToUpdate(int lastRowCount)
{
    int currentRowCount = getData().Rows.Count;

    // if the number of rows has changed, time to reload the page
    return (currentRowCount != lastRowCount);
}
```

Lastly, we just need to update the javascript to call this PageMethod at a regular interval, and reload the page if it returns True:

```
setInterval(function () {
    var lastRowCount = $('#<%= hiddenRowCount.ClientID %>').val();

    PageMethods.NeedToUpdate(lastRowCount, function (result) {
        if (result === true)
            $('#refresh').click();
    });
}, 30000);
```

Comment: can you give me any idea what that static method may look like? would i have to create another connection to the SQL? even then, how would i check to see if anything had been changed? I am happy writing the AJAX side of it, and making a BOOL in the code behind, but not sure how that method should query the SQL and then return true or false. further help i would appreacite